# Interesting Hamiltonian System

Tags: classical-mechanics, mathematical-physics, differential-geometry, hamiltonian-formalism, topology

The definition of a Hamiltonian system I am working with is a triple $(X,\omega, H)$ where $(X,\omega)$ is a symplectic manifold and $H\in C^\infty(X)$ is the Hamiltonian function.

I am wondering if someone can give me an interesting, or useful, example of a Hamiltonian system for which $X$ is not the cotangent bundle of a manifold.

Comment: Related: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/126676/2451 , http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/32095/2451 and http://mathoverflow.net/q/147395/13917

Answer (score 2):

Often $X$ is a coadjoint orbit of a Lie group. These have a natural symplectic structure; see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symplectic_reduction